# Any recommendations around caching for light-4j applications?

Tags: light-4j

I want to add a cache layer at the rest API endpoint to reduce the latency and increase the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kafka Streams, then the local in-memory key/value store or RocksDB key/value store is pretty fast to cache any event sourcing aggregates/projections. RocksDB also gives us an option to cache a huge amount of data on the local drive for the service. If you are looking for the local in-memory cache for the traditional database, then https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine is very good. For the distributed cache, we are using Hazelcast community edition which is free. It is a little bit tricky to set it up with Kubernetes though.

Comment: Also Redis is a great key/value store. Its a #1 in its segment: https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/key-value+store
(while RocksDB is #16 in ratings).
See comparison: https://db-engines.com/en/system/Redis%3BRocksDB

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention Redis. We support Redis for distributed session management in light-session-4j. https://github.com/networknt/light-session-4j